# Continue to running the application in the background?

Tags: maui

I need my app to run in the background as my app keeps track of a workout's total time once it starts, when the user completes a set in the exercise, it has a timer that countdowns their rest time, say 30 seconds or so, when that is completed it plays a sound to tell them to do their next set.

I need it to not terminate, as say if there resting, they switch to their music app the play something else, or go to facebook and play around until their rest is complete, the app will terminate and then they have to restart their whole workout.

Everything works fine in the Android version of the app. Looking up different ways to handle this, I found only Xamarin documentation on background tasks:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/

Then I also went through their walk-through on updating locations, but that is written in pretty much all iOS, view controllers, and all, is that what needs to be done?

I had some success, as the set timer will at least finish, but will not play the sound, and once it is finished the app is terminated my code:

```
   private async Task playSoundAsync()
{             
     var file = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("finalbeepsound.mp3");
     player = audioManager.CreatePlayer(file);
     await Task.Run( () =>  player.Play());
}


public void StartRestTimer()
{             
    Debug.WriteLine("Start Rest Timer hit.");   
    if (Set.Rest != 0)             
    {                 
        IsCountDownShowing = true;                 
        IsSaveButtonShowing = false;                  
        IsCountingDown = true;                 
        SecondsRemaining = Set.Rest;                 
        timer = Application.Current.Dispatcher.CreateTimer();                 
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);                 
        timer.Tick += async (sender, args) =>                 
        {                     
               SecondsRemaining--;                      
               if (SecondsRemaining == 0)                     
               {                         
                   IsCountingDown = false;                         
                   IsCountDownShowing = false;                         
                   IsSaveButtonShowing = true;                         
                   await playSoundAsync();                         
                   timer.Stop();                     
}              };                 
               timer.Start();             
      }                     
}

using Foundation;
 using UIKit;
  namespace PumpPal; 
 [Register("AppDelegate")] 
public class AppDelegate : MauiUIApplicationDelegate { 
    nint taskID;    
protected override MauiApp CreateMauiApp() => MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp();      

public override void OnActivated(UIApplication application)     {         
Console.WriteLine("On Activated called, App is active."); 
             
}      

public override void WillEnterForeground(UIApplication application)     {  
       Console.WriteLine("App will enter foreground");               
       UIApplication.SharedApplication.EndBackgroundTask(taskID);  
   }      

public override void OnResignActivation(UIApplication application)     {                    
        Console.WriteLine("OnResignActivation called, App moving to inactive state."); 
        taskID = UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginBackgroundTask(() => { });
}     

public override void DidEnterBackground(UIApplication application)     {         
    Console.WriteLine("App entering background state.");     
}      
public override void WillTerminate(UIApplication application)     {         
     Console.WriteLine("App is terminating");     
}
```

Comment: From the docs:[Application set up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-walkthroughs/location-walkthrough#application-set-up), have you added the `UIBackgroundModes` key for the auido like `<key>UIBackgroundModes</key><array> <string>audio</string></array>`?

Comment: Yes that is set

Comment: Thanks for the update, you may need to create a `AVAudioPlayer`  and then Play the audio in the `DidEnterBackground` method.

Answer (score 0):

To play the sound in the background, you need to use [AVAudioPlayer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/avfoundation.avaudioplayer?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) to play the mp3 when entering background(`DidEnterBackground`) and stop when entering foreground(`WillEnterForeground`), see [Application Lifecycle Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/introduction-to-backgrounding-in-ios#application-lifecycle-methods).

You can refer to the sample code below:

1.Create a [AVAudioPlayer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/avfoundation.avaudioplayer?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) in `CreateMauiApp`:

```
public AVAudioPlayer backgroundPlayer { get; set; }
protected override MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
{
            //var file = FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("XXX.mp3");
            NSUrl fileurl = NSBundle.MainBundle.GetUrlForResource("XXX", "mp3");
            NSError error;
            backgroundPlayer = new AVAudioPlayer(fileurl, "mp3",out error);
          backgroundPlayer.NumberOfLoops = -1;//repeat

            return MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp();
}
```

2.Implement `Play` and `StopPlay` method:

```
void KeepLivePlayMusic (){
            AVAudioSession session = AVAudioSession.SharedInstance();
            session.SetActive(true);
            session.SetCategory(AVAudioSessionCategory.Playback);
            backgroundPlayer.Play();
}

void StopPlayMusic()
{

    if (backgroundPlayer !=null) {
             backgroundPlayer.Stop();
             backgroundPlayer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

3.Play the sound when entering background(`DidEnterBackground`) and stop when entering foreground(`WillEnterForeground`):

```
public override void WillEnterForeground(UIApplication application)
{
        base.WillEnterForeground(application);
        StopPlayMusic();
}

public override void DidEnterBackground(UIApplication application)
{
        base.DidEnterBackground(application);
        KeepLivePlayMusic();
}
```

Comment: May I know whether your issue has been solved or not? If not, please share it in here. We can work together to figure it out.